# Call service from specific node

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, node, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Scenario: System of multiple nodes able to be configured during runtime via one master.
Idea: every node provides a service (ex: configure_node(config)) which can be called by the master. Each node is uniquely named and does a job specific to the configuration it got.

Problem: I cant find anything about calling a service on a specific node (ex: NodeA/configure_node). Of course it could be realised using Pub/Sub but I would appreciate the RPC like features of the services. Is there anything I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338654/call-service-from-specific-node/) by [unterbuchse](https://answers.ros.org/users/49786/unterbuchse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably aware, but: your described setup would go against the idea of location independence / agnosticity that is one of the main advantages of ROS (or any other framework/middleware with location independence).

> I cant find anything about calling a service on a specific node (ex: NodeA/configure_node).

yes, and I believe that is because of what I wrote above.

Using service servers started on private nodehandles would make this possible without too much fiddling with internals.

---

Just to avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info), could you describe why you want to do this?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unterbuchse](https://answers.ros.org/users/49786/unterbuchse/) on 2019-11-26**:
As I stated above, the idea is to call some method on a named node with the "luxury" of RPC like request/response behavior. Of course I am aware of the term "Service" as described in, for example, Service Oriented Architectures, which indeed focuses on non monolithic systems where it is not important who computes something but rather that a specific task can be handled. Currently I cannot see any other RPC like system provided by ROS, maybe you guys have some ideas. The workaround will be: let the nodes subscribe to their respective function call (ie: NodeA/configure_node) and then let the main program publish the configurations. This would work but not give the neat RPC features.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-27**:
It sounds like you want to use nodes almost as libraries and create a monolithic system out of something that is inherently distributed.

In any case: as I wrote in my earlier comment: advertise your service servers on private nodehandles.

That way you get `$node_name/$service_name` instead of `$service_name` as the identifier for the service.

In service clients you can then pass `$node_name/$service_name` and invoke `$service_name` on `$node_name` specifically.

See how `dynamic_reconfigure` does this, as it sounds like it does something similar.

> The workaround will be: let the nodes subscribe to their respective function call (ie: NodeA/configure_node) and then let the main program publish the configurations. This would work but not give the neat RPC features.

I'm not sure this is what I just described, as I don't really understand your description (nor why it is a work-around).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-27**:\

> As I stated above, the idea is to call some method on a named node with the "luxury" of RPC like request/response behavior. [..]

yes, but you haven't actually told us *why* you want to do that.

It could well be there is some other design pattern or interaction scheme that is better suited for what your actual goal is.

Right now we wouldn't know, as you don't describe it. So we can only discuss the problem you have identified with the solution you've already decided upon.

**Comment by [unterbuchse](https://answers.ros.org/users/49786/unterbuchse/) on 2019-11-28**:
The tip about the private nodehandlers and the use of the ~ made the trick for me. Thanks @gvdhoorn